# How to get D-Link DWA-547 working on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, atheros

I got a D-Link DWA-547 Wifi card which is supposed to work out-of-the-box with Linux. Says so here: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k/products/external

While lspci does list the device, NetworkManager doesn't seem to allow me to configure Wifi. lsmod also shows that ath9k isn't loaded. Manually loading with 'modprobe ath9k' doesn't help.

How do I get this card working on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the driver does indeed work, just not as I expected.

From observing Ubuntu's network indicator over the week I noticed that WiFi will spontaneously "just work". Often after a few hours of using Ubuntu the WiFi will just start working randomly. This is impractical but it does work.

So, I guess that answers my question. I just have a different sort of question in my hands now.